# Docstrings in C extensions to Python?

Tags: python, cpython, python-c-extension

When creating a C extension to Python, is it possible to be able to somehow write comments that are exposed as [docstrings](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/docstrings.html) to users of the extension?

Comment: You may already be aware of it, but if not: You might want to investigate Cython. You write Python-style code, add some type declarations, and it gets translated to C and compiled.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Docstrings for **types** can be included as the [`tp_doc`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_doc) member in the `PyTypeObject` structure, see [an example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics).

Docstrings for **functions** can be included in the [`ml_doc`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMethodDef) field of the [module's method table](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function).  If you want your docstrings to be "physically close" to the actual functions, you could include string constants above your function definitions which you reference in the method table.

Docstrings for **methods** can be assigned to the [`doc`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMemberDef) field in the [type's member table](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#id3).

Docstrings for **modules** can be passed as a parameter to the [`Py_InitModule3()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/allocation.html#c.Py_InitModule3) or [`Py_InitModule4()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/allocation.html#c.Py_InitModule4) functions.

---

**UPDATE**: Python3 does not support `Py_InitModule3()`, and the method has been replaced with [`PyModule_Create()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/module.html?highlight=pymodule_create#c.PyModule_Create).